# how to split the data from $_POST var_dump in php

Tags: php

hi guy's this is my first time using `var_dump` in php function.
i am really don't know how to split the data from that `var_dump`
maybe someone can help me to give an example for split that data. i hope the method is simple for i can understand. i have try to search it in this forum and i can understand it.

this is the data i have got from `var_dump
[image: Data from Var_dump]

please give me a simple example for that.
an please explain it for me.
i just use this code for get the data. because its my 1st time.

```
<?php
include('../../Connections/koneksi.php');
$tableData = var_dump($_POST);

echo $array;
?>
```

This is the actual data
http://jsfiddle.net/minervaz/us4a9gkL/

Comment: Please post actual data not the image

Comment: the actual data of the array @AlivetoDie ?

Comment: Yes, if it's very large the some part of it, like 4-5 indexes data. if it's small then full data please

Comment: Not clear by `how to split the data from that var_dump`

Comment: Yes he doesn't specify.The question is unclear...

Comment: i want to get the data from var dump as string. without the ` / , and etc`

Comment: @MinervazMine so basically you have to decode and to print not with echo but with var_dump() or print_r() functions

Comment: As i said we need actual data not image. no one can solve your problem. Do `echo"<pre/>";print_r($_POST);` before  this line `$tableData = var_dump($_POST);` and copy paste your output here in your question, meanwhile comment these two lines :-`$tableData =var_dump($_POST);echo $array;`

Comment: @AlivetoDie i have give the actual data with jsfiddle above

Comment: @MinervazMine well i don't see any form in your jsfiddle. I do not have any idea how are you getting these data and what is your logic with $_POST?

Comment: @MrAlb sorry i think i have send wrong fiddle. that fiddle just contain the array of the data . i have update the fiddle like this http://jsfiddle.net/minervaz/us4a9gkL/3/

Comment: @MinervazMine it works now, i tested in my pc. In you javascript code you have used alert(data); So you can't use alert to display objects or arrays.you have to use console.log(data) or alert(JSON.stringify(data)); to see result that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can't use `echo` to display an object or array.So use `var_dump()` or `print_r()`

**Javascript code :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click','#display_data',function(e){
    var convertTableToJson = function()
        {
            var rows = [];
            $('.table-bordered tr:has(td)').each(function(i, n){
                var $row = $(n);
                rows.push([
                    $row.find('td:eq(0)').text(),
                    $row.find('td:eq(1)').text(),
                    $row.find('td:eq(2)').text(),
                    $row.find('td:eq(3)').text(),
                    $row.find('td:eq(4)').text(),
                    $row.find('td:eq(5)').text(),
                    $row.find('td:eq(6)').text(),
                    $row.find('td:eq(7)').text(),
                ]);
            });
            return JSON.stringify(rows);
        };
   var data = convertTableToJson();
    $.ajax({
    data: { 'table-bordered': data },  
    type:"POST",
    url:"../php/tagihan/save_data.php",
            success: function(data){
                //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                console.log(data);
            }            
    });

});
</script>
```

**PHP CODE**:

```
if(isset($_POST['table-bordered'])){
    $array=json_decode($_POST['table-bordered'],true);
    print_r($array);


}
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 101200
            [1] => WCB
            [2] => 101
            [3] => 5006540050
            [4] => 1
            [5] => 10.08.2017
            [6] => 23.970
            [7] => KG
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 101200
            [1] => WCB
            [2] => 101
            [3] => 5006539985
            [4] => 1
            [5] => 10.08.2017
            [6] => 42.970
            [7] => KG
        )

)
```

Comment: i use this and give data as `null`

Comment: i have try your code in my pc. and i didn't get the array of the data in my console log. why like that?

Comment: did i need to add more library for that ?
i just use `jquery.min.js` for the library version `2.1.3`

Comment: @MinervazMine it is imposible i just tested again and again.it works fine.I just used your code in jsfiddle and Jquery is ok.I think that problem is how you ogranized the code.I just put the html and js code in the index.php and the php code in the save_data.php and executed index.php via localhost.Try to comment console.log and to uncomment alert in the js code

Comment: hmmm...
that make  me confuse.

Comment: i place the html code alone in index.php. then the js alone in input_data.js. and the php at save_data.php. and no result i cant get  T_T

Comment: @MinervazMine I am sorry man, if you want my code just write the email here to send the working code.

Comment: can i check it?
i want to compare with my code
i want to know why my code wont work

Comment: this is my email `jack.henaldy@gmail.com`

Comment: my question just for doing insert the table data into the database..
but i get many thing stuck there. 1st one is passing my array data of my table to the php. that's why i try to use many method to get that array

Comment: i think it work.
but im still cant get the console log data .. xD.
thx bro

Comment: You are wellcome